# PDF Miner way of processing text

Tags: python, pdfminer

I'm not sure the title is clear enough but I'll try to explain better here.

I have a PDF and I need to see if it's contain some char. For exemple, there is this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDo7z.jpg

I need to get the line containing "contrat n° XXXXX". What I've done from now, is getting the text, but here is what I have :

```
Client
Contrat
Produit

n°XXXXXX
n°XXXXX
XXXXX
```

But what I want is something like this :

```
Client n°XXXX
Contrat n°XXXX
Produit XXXXXXX
```

is there a way to achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: The way understand your question, it is not really about extracting the text from the PDF (because you already succeeded with that) but about transforming the extracted text into some other structure. In my opinion it would help if you edited your question accordingly in order to focus it on the actual problem.

Comment: I edit my post, hope it's clearer now